# mod_rewrite not working in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my .htaccess file which is in the root of my directory, I have this;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^website-comments/webid/([^/]*)$ /website-comments?webid=$1 [L]
```

But for some reason it is not rewriting the URL, if what I'm thinking is correct then if a user visits www.website.com/website-comments?webid=1 it should change the url to www.website.com/website-comments/webid/1 but it doesn't seem to be working, am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**

Other HTACCESS RULES

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: On your server, the script which should ultimately actually be executed is `/website-comments?webid=$1`?  mod_rewrite does not automatically change links directly to that resource into your preferred pretty URL -you need to write a rule that does the redirection to the pretty URL first. Please clarify your needs a little more with example input URLs, output URLs, and what script ultimately executes the request.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski so if I just typed something like website-comments/webid/1 into the url it should work but it just won't redirect if I try and access it by clicking a link?

Comment: With your current rule, accessing the URL `website-comments/webid/1` would silently rewrite to serve `?webid=1`. But if a user clicked an old, non-pretty link that pointed directly to `/website-comments?webid=1`, that is the URL he would ultimately see. You need _another_ rule to first redirect that into `/website-comments/webid/1` then silently serve the script like it does already.  Is your goal that end users never see `/website-comments?webid=1`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski ahhh I see! thank you very much, if you write that into an answer I'll accept it for you

Comment: @user3263978 Ok, I think I've worked out the rules you'll need below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache's mod_rewrite when used with basic rules can silently serve an internal URL to your users, but it cannot *enforce* the use of that internal URL with just the same simple rule.  Typically if you want your end users to *never* use the actual URL (`/website-comments?webid=123` in your case) you need to first provide a rule which redirects away from that URL by matching it in the original HTTP request using Apache's variable `%{THE_REQUEST}`.

```
RewriteEngine On
# probably don't actually need RewriteBase
RewriteBase /

# First match the URL which the user requested. If it is ?webid=N
# do an actual redirection to the pretty URL
# This will grab digits from the query string to use in %1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} webid=(\d+)
# ...only doing this for website-comments -- a permanent redirect to the pretty URL
# so the client makes a new request to the pretty URL that won't match the above condition 
# on the next trip.
#
# Since the [R] will automatically append the old query string, add a ?
# onto the end to clear out the query string so this rule doesn't match again and
# go into an infinite loop.
RewriteRule website-comments /website-comments/webid/%1? [L,R=301]

# Then apply your existing rule to rewrite internally to the target resource
RewriteRule ^website-comments/webid/([^/]*)$ /website-comments?webid=$1 [L]
```

The above `(\d+)` assumes that `webid` will only be an integer.  If that's not true and it could include other characters, consider using `([^&]+)` instead to match everything up to the next `&` or end of the string.

Comment: on the line that says [L,R=301] at the end, should that be $1? or is it actually %1?

Comment: It's actually `%1`.  `()` groups matched in `RewriteRule` use `$` but groups matched in `RewriteCond` use `%`.

Comment: okay  I've done that, but now I'm getting a 500 internal server error throughout my website

Comment: Ok I think I found it.  The `[R=301]` automatically appends the original query string, so `webid=123` gets sent to the subsequent redirect, resulting in `/website-comments/webid/123?webid=123`. That again matches in `THE_REQUEST` and goes into a loop. The solution is to clear the original query string with a `?` on `/website-comments/webid/%1?`  It works in my testing.

Comment: okay makes sense! I've changed that but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Look in your apache error log then to see what the error actually is.

Comment: And verify that if you comment out the last line (your original) and go to `http://example.com/website-comments?webid=123` that it does indeed first redirect to `http://example.com/website-comments/webid/123` (which would then probably 404) so you know you've gotten halfway there.  Also, do you have any other rewrite rules before or after this? Often I get through a long debugging process only to find out there's a set of WordPress rules or similar in place...

Comment: okay no I still get the error throughout, and I've just updated my answer with my other rule. Also I put the .htaccess file in a validator and it says that this line; RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ?webid=(\d+) cannot compile regular expressions

Comment: That just means that the validator you used doesn't know how to parse it. Apache does and it will work. The other ruleset you posted is a catch-all.  You need to make sure that those lines are the _last_ thing. So the order is 1) `THE_REQUEST` pair 2) RewriteRule like your original 3) catch-all rule.  Also, the catch-all makes me suspect now that `website-comments` isn't actually a directory but a file like `website-comments.php`?  If that's the case, you need that in the rule as `RewriteRule ^website-comments/webid/([^/]*)$ /website-comments.php?webid=$1 [L]`

Comment: Oh wait, I just spotted a problem with the regex. Instead of `?webid=(\d+)` it should either be `\?webid=(\d+)` or just `webid=(\d+)`.  The inability to parse the regex really is due to the `?` on the front, which was misinterpreted as an unescaped regex `?`

Comment: okay brilliant! thank you that's fixed the 500 error, however my url now just says /website-comments/webid/ without the number

Comment: wait never mind, that was my fault it is putting numbers on the end now but is sometimes resulting in a redirect loop

Comment: _Sometimes_? That is suspicious.  Sometimes browsers cache redirects aggressively and that can make it hard to debug. Change `301` to `302` temporarily to avoid that, and also test the same URLs which appear to loop in a different browser.  Beyond that, you need to identify a pattern in which ones loop.

Comment: yes you're right it was a caching issue, have deleted it and is all fine now! Thank you for all your help

Comment: @user3263978 Glad to hear it. mod_rewrite can be a lot more difficult to debug than a normal code issue, owing to all these environmental factors.

Answer (score 1):

> if what I'm thinking is correct then if a user visits www.website.com/website-comments?webid=1 it should change the url to www.website.com/website-comments/webid/1

No. The *incoming* URI "from the wild" (typed in by a user, supplied by a bookmark or search engine, or a link in your site) is going to be the SEO form: `/website-comments/webid/1`. The job of .htaccess is to change that to the *dynamic* format with a Query String, which your PHP script can digest (read the element in $_GET): `/website-comments.php?webid=1`. So, you have it backwards.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^website-comments/webid/([0-9]+)/?$  /website-comments.php?webid=$1 [L]
```

would be one way to do it, and may meet your needs.

Answer (score -1):

try this (switch) RewriteRule parameters

```
RewriteRule ^/website-comments?webid=([^/]*)$ website-comments/webid/$1[L]
```

Comment: Nope, hasn't changed a thing

Comment: The query string is never passed into `RewriteRule` so the left side will never match here. It has to be handled in `RewriteCond`.